# First or second syllable accent for "detail"?

Tags: pronunciation

I used to pronounce 'detail' as ['di:teil] with accent on the first syllable. However, these days I hear people (and on the radio) say [di'teil] with accent on the second syllable. Is my pronunciation incorrect? Is there a regional preference for this?

Comment: Related: [Is it more common for the noun “research” to be stressed on the first or second syllable among educated native speakers of American English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/355823)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/detail), your pronunciation is fine as both are acceptable to convey the usual noun and verb form meanings of the word.

According to this American, /ˈdiːteɪl/ is far more common from the mouths of my fellow Americans.

Macmillan has the [British](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/pronunciation/british/detail) as /ˈdiːteɪl/, and the [American](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/pronunciation/american/detail) as both /dɪˈteɪl/ and /ˈdiˌteɪl/.

Comment: In *British* English, /dɪˈteɪl/ is a **verb**, meaning *to remove the tail from*.

Comment: I was hoping that was the case.  M-W does not offer this definition.  Thanks for saving me some virtual shoe leather.

Comment: Yeah, well you'll have to wait for some Americans to upvote the answer (always assuming it's true they really do put the accent on the second syllable when they mean *a small point*). I'm not saying they don't, obviously, but **I** don't, so I can't casually upvote you saying both are fine.

Comment: I don't know which is more common here in north middle US, but think that it's often said with relatively little accent on either syllable.

Comment: @jwpat7: in AmE, I find it to be an accent on both, a [spondee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spondee).