# Is it more common for the noun "research" to be stressed on the first or second syllable among educated native speakers of American English?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, stress

Which of the two common pronunciations of the noun *research* is more common among educated native American English speakers?

1. /rɪ **ˈsɝt͡ʃ**/ with the stress on the second syllable
2. /**ˈriː** sɚt͡ʃ/ with the stress on the first syllable

Comment: In my experience (WA and PA), rē is more common. In some circles, usually tied to education, ri is the common noun form.

Comment: Interestingly this pattern goes against standard verb noun syllable stress patterns http://www.english-at-home.com/pronunciation/noun-and-verb-syllable-stress/

Comment: @Unrelated: no, it doesn't; not really. The word started out as /rɪˈsərtʃ/ for both the noun and the verb, and in some regions the noun has switched and started conforming to the standard verb-noun syllable stress pattern.

Comment: @PeterShor you're right, I got turned around

Comment: Highly dependent on your locale. In some areas of the US it would be "ree-search". In others it would be "ri-search".

Comment: And if you want to get into all the various accents of the US technically it can be pronounced many different ways ;) In the northeast (like Boston or New York) whether you stress "ree" or "ri" the "search" syllable becomes "such" as in "ree-such". In the south it would be "ree-sURch".

Comment: In my own usage as a teacher, I use the word REE-search when talking about the product or result of the activity. When I tell a class to find information on their own, I emphasize ri-SEARCH.

Comment: Both pronunciations are common. Many people use both. Depends on how they want to emphasize the word in a sentence.

Comment: Graduate of West Virginia University, I would totally agree with using REE-search for the product and ri-SEARCH as the activity.

Comment: @Kace36: Traditionally, shouldn't it be *resoich* in New York? In actuality, most educated New Yorkers have dropped that pronunciation and would say *research* today (even if they still say *cawfee* and *Zaybah's*).

Comment: @PeterShor I think I've only ever heard the /rɪˈsərtʃ/ pronunciation for the noun variant so my impression too is that it does seem to violate the standard noun syllable stress patterns, as https://english.stackexchange.com/users/59495/unrelated suggests. I did a quick experiment on youglish.com and it does seem to confirm my intuition.  I've tried about 80 examples (40 noun forms 40 verb forms in American English) and all the verb forms were pronounced /ˈriː sɚt͡ʃ/ and the only examples of /rɪˈsərtʃ/  came up in the noun variants and only twice.

Answer (score 1):

There are a large number of two-syllable English words (see a list at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial-stress-derived_noun#List)) where the verb is accented on the second syllable and the noun is accented on the first syllable.

The [dictionaries](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/research) say that the accent on *research* can be either on the first or second syllable, but I suspect a large number of people (like me) treat it as one of this class of words, with the noun accesnted on the first syllable and the verb on the second. The word *research* is included in the list I link to above.

Answer (score 0):

I went to college, worked as a computer programmer and in database design. I've lived in Louisiana, Mississippi and Arkansas. I've always heard the word 'research' pronounced with the stress on the first syllable.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

This is a great topic because it highlights the difference between formal/standard and informal American English. It also speaks to how people are educated regarding grammar and the pronunciation of words over time. Although "research" has two different pronunciations (REE-search, noun) and (ri-Search, verb), many Americans were not taught this rule. Thus, it has been normalized and has become acceptable (or tolerated) in most circles to pronounce both the noun and verb as (REE-Search).

As an educated person and a former English teacher, I am embarrassed to admit that I was pronouncing the noun and verb as "REE-search" for most of my career. I have only recently started to be more cognizant of stressing the correct syllable when using research as noun or verb.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).